# OpenGL Shaders ERROR: 0:1 "version '330' is not supported?

Tags: c, macos, opengl, glsl, glfw

When compiling the main.c function I get the following GLSL errors:

```
Failed to compile 35633 type shader.
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '330' is not supported
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version
ERROR: 0:2: 'layout' : syntax error: syntax error

Failed to compile 35632 type shader.
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '330' is not supported
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version
ERROR: 0:2: 'layout' : syntax error: syntax error
```

...The 35633 type shader being the vertex shader, and the 35632 type shader being my fragment shader. I see that some people have trouble using OpenGL shaders on macOS, which I am on Big Sur, but most of the help I have searched for online for these errors have been not useful for me.

Below is my main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <OpenGL/gl.h>

#include "window.h"


void gameLoop(float delta)
{

}



 /*

 Create Shaders




*/


static unsigned int compileShader(char* source, unsigned int type)
{
unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
glShaderSource(id,1,&source,NULL); //have to pass in the memory address of pointer
glCompileShader(id);

//ERROR HANDELING. 

int result;
//get shader (integer)(vector (or pointer!) )
glGetShaderiv(id,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&result);    //check if shader compiled
        if(!result) //results is either GL_TRUE or GL_FALSE     
        {
            //Shader did not compile successfully.
            int length;
            //          Get the message length.
            glGetShaderiv(id,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
            char *message = (char*)malloc(length);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(id,length,&length,message);
            printf("Failed to compile %u type shader.\n",type);
            printf("%s\n",message);
            //delete shader cause it didn't compile successfully.
            glDeleteShader(id);
            return 0;
        }
return id;
 }


 static unsigned int CreateShader(char* vertexShader, char* fragmentShader)
 {
unsigned int program = glCreateProgram(); //glCreateProgram returns an unsigned int
unsigned int vs = compileShader(vertexShader,GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
unsigned int fs = compileShader(fragmentShader,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

//Link both the vertex shader and the fragment shader into one file.

glAttachShader(program,vs); //Attaches a shader object to a program object.
glAttachShader(program,fs); //Attaches both of the shader objects to the program.
glLinkProgram(program);     //Links a program object.
glValidateProgram(program); //Validates a program. Checks to see if the executables 
                            //program can execute given the current OpenGL State. 


//Delete tha shaders (because it is linked to our program.) Different from           
glDeleteShader(vs);
glDeleteShader(fs);

//Return the program since it has both of the shaders in it.
return program;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(!Window_init(800,600,"WINDOW"))
    {
    printf("Problem loading window.\n");
    return 1;
    }




float positions[6] = {
    -0.5f,-0.5f,
    0.0f,0.5f,
    0.5f,-0.5f
};


unsigned int VBO, VAO;
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6*sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float)*2, 0);




//create a shader 
char *vertexShader = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
strcpy(vertexShader,"#version 330 core\nlayout(location = 0) in vec4          position;\nvoid main()\n{\ngl_Position=position;\n\0}"); 
//version 330 core means using GLSL, not using deprecated functions.

char *fragmentShader = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
strcpy(fragmentShader,"#version 330 core\nlayout(location = 0) out vec4 color;\nvoid main()\n{\ncolor=vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);\n\0}"); 



unsigned int shader = CreateShader(vertexShader,fragmentShader); //after creating shader, 
glUseProgram(shader);


while(!Window_shouldClose())
{
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    glfwPollEvents();
}


glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
glDeleteProgram(shader);
glfwTerminate();

Window_destroy();

return 0;

}
```

....and here is my window.h

```
        #ifndef WINDOW_H
    #define WINDOW_H
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <GL/glew.h>
    #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

    #include <OpenGL/gl.h>

    static GLFWwindow* window;

    static double last = 0.0;
    static double now = 0.0;
    static float delta = 1.0f;


    int Window_init(int width, int height, char* title);

    void Window_update(void (*update)(float));

    int Window_shouldClose();

    void Window_destroy();

    int Window_init(int width, int height, char* title)
    {
        if(!glfwInit())
        {
            printf("GLFW NOT INITIALIZED SUCCESFULLY\n");
            return 0;
        }

    
        window = glfwCreateWindow(width,height,title,NULL,NULL);
        //ALWAYS PUT WINDOW HINTS AFTER CREAITNG THE WINDOW.
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

        if(!window)
        {
            glfwTerminate();
            return 0;
        }
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;


        
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0,width,height,0,-1,1); //Orthographic view (??) (left,right,bottom,top,nearVal,farVal)
                                        //Left, right = specify the coordinates for the left and right vertial
                                        //clipping planes.
                                        //Bottom, top
                                        //Specify the coordinates for the bottom and top horizontal clipping planes.
                                        //nearVal, farVal
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        {
            printf("Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }




    void Window_update(void (*update)(float))
    {
        last = glfwGetTime();

        (*update)(delta);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window); //swap the front and back buffers
        glfwPollEvents();
        now = glfwGetTime();
        delta = (float)(now-last) * 10.0f;

    }
    int Window_shouldClose()
    {
        return glfwWindowShouldClose(window);
    }

    void Window_destroy()
    {
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    #endif // WINDOW_h
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you're (trying) to target Core contexts then what are those fixed-function matrix stack calls (`glMatrixMode()` & co.) doing in `Window_init()`?

Comment: I am totally beginning to learn how OpenGL is so I was just following tutorials and not honestly sure what those functions do. Haha

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4):

Calling `glfwWindowHint()` *after* `glfwCreateWindow()` won't do anything useful; it only affects the *next* `glfwCreateWindow()` call.

So your GL version and Core-ness hints fly off into the ether and macOS gives you a GL 2.1-era context (which most certainly doesn't support the `core` keyword in `#version` directives) since you didn't request otherwise.